# SVD class in opencv with vector<point3f> as input

Tags: opencv

I would like to apply the function svd in openCV. I take a 
vector < Point3f> and assign it to the a svd opbject I created. But the during run time there is an error of

```
"Assertion failed<type ==CV_32F || type == CV_64F>"
```

What is the problem in my case?

Comment: I think my problem is I do not know how to use the SVD class correctly.Would anyone can provide me a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the openCV classes only work with a specific input ie 3 columns of floats, vs single column of point3f.

You may have to convert the vector into a cv::Mat eg, `cv::Mat tmp(myvector)` and then perhaps reshape the mat into 3 columns of 1 channel - eg. `tmp.reshape(1)` when you pass it into the svd call.

Comment: Thus do you mean the class svd only accept Mat as its input? With refering to the the official reference ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/df7/classcv_1_1SVD.html#gsc.tab=0)), the input type can be "InputArray".  
And what is the purpose of reshape  here?